# JSTL format String with Mask

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, string-formatting

is anybody know how to format `String` with mask using jstl tags? let say you want to show confidential credit card number in list and you just want to show first 4 digit and else will be masked with * something like :

```
1234-****-****-****
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything out of the box to do this.  The `fmt` namespaced tags are about formatting numbers and dates and i18n stuff, but nothing about string formatting.  If you don't want to be doing this in your presentation layer with scriptlets or function invocations, you might want to consider adding another model property for the obfuscated CC number that way you can do the formatting in Java where it will be much easier.

Comment: yah i think i can mask it in java model layer, making a getter with mask maybe? just curious about it. thanks anyway.

Comment: You should play around with it being a concrete separate property vs just a getter that does the masking on the fly.  You'd be surprised how many times the getter gets called to just display the property once on the page.  Probably not a big deal as the format logic is no computationally intense, but just something to think about.

Comment: Good point of view. But i think it no need to make new property since no computation like you said. Thank so much!

Comment: If you are concerned about the security of this number, then it is paramount that you convert/mask this number before the presentation layer.